# Set frontpage to have url path

Tags: 8

I am trying to homepage as `<domain>/url_path`, which Drupal allows via site configuration.

However how Drupal internally does it is by setting up `url_path` as homepage and a 301 redirect from `url_path` to `/`

Now what I am trying is to avoid this 301 redirect and open homepage as `<domain>/url_path`.

The reason it matters is because we have setup a logic to redirect request based on url_path to different cms so any request to `<domain>` will be served from non Drupal CMS and `<domain>/url_path/*` should go to Drupal and `<domain>/url_path` acts as kind of hompepage of subsite on Drupal but problem comes when Drupal redirects `<domain/url_path>` to `<domain>` and then request never comes back to Drupal since it get resolves via non Drupal cms via cloudflare rules.

I know the workaroound would be not to have `url_path` as front page but then I have to programmatically set site logo, breadcrumb `Home` link and `<front>` to act as `<domain>/url_path`

I am looking for a way to avoid `<domian>/url_path` redirect to `<domain>` which should in turn fix everything else.

Comment: This looks like you have a route normalizer installed, like for example the one included in the module Redirect. Independent of this it might be easier to solve this outside of Drupal by serving Drupal from the subdirectory `url_path/`.

Comment: You could edit the .htaccess file to create a redirect to your path, then you would also have to reset the Drupal homepage in the settings. However, this would have an impact on the site SEO.